# How to structure code in Go packages and folders?

Tags: go

I have read all kinds of articles covering this issue and there are a lot of different approaches out there.
I'm new to Go and I'm trying to learn the best practices instead of picking up some bad styles right in the beginning.

Coming from languages that have classes, I'm trying not to apply everything I've learnt over the years when learning a new language like Go.

Which brings up my first point: Is it considered a good style in Go to structure you program in packages and folders?

From what I've read so far, some people recommend doing that, so I went for a structure like this (my actual program is much bigger and therefor qualifies for the 'move code to packages' approach):

```
.
├── bin
│   └── helloworld
└── src
    ├── github.com
    │   ├── SOMEUSER
    │   │   └── helloworld
    │   │       ├── main.go
    │   │       ├── main_test.go
    │   │       ├── greeter
    │   │       │   └── talker.go
    │   │       └── person.go
```

So as you can see I moved some new code to a separate package which in this case would be `greeter`. I import this package in my main.go file (I've read multiple times already that this approach is recommended instead of doing the import like `import ./greeter`) :

```
package main

import "github.com/SOMEUSER/helloworld/greeter"

func main() {
    greeter.Hello()
}
```

which then calls the function `Hello()` in my `greeter` package.
So far so good.

But here comes my actual question (assuming that the above structure would be the recommended way to structure code in Go):

How can I now use any function, struct, etc. which was declared in any of the files in my `main` package (here I have some serious doubts if this would be the way to go, no pun intended)?

So let's assume I declared some struct in `person.go` called `Person`. This struct is now used at several parts of my application, and it'd be good to also use it in my included (local) package, like this:

```
package greeter

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
    p := Person{Name: "Steve"}
    fmt.Println(p.Name)
}
```

When trying to build this, it throws an `undefined: Person` error.

If you could point me in the right direction and enlighten me about the recommended way and style how this is approached in Go, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: In Go, a package is self contained. It needs to import everything that it refers to. It is idiomatic to start with a main package and then split functional units off into their own packages when refactoring. I don't mean a month down the track I mean like a couple hours after you start coding on a problem. If you split things off into their own packages too soon you end up in a situation where you start making packages for things that you'd be better off using == for. Keep your code together in one package until it looks obvious to you that something could be split off in a self contained way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the `Person` struct, you would need to import the `github.com/SOMEUSER/helloworld` package and use it like `main.Person`.
However, it isn't possible because you can't import a `main` package and it would create a circular depedency.

Generally, I export into sub-packages the following code :

- Helpers completely unrelated to the package
- Part that are independant and could be a third-party library
- Part that are related but don't have dependancies on `main` code

Now, keep in mind that it really is a question of complexity. Having many files but low complexity doesn't justify a subpackage.

Answer (score 1):

There are two "solutions" here.

1) Put the code back in the main package until you know what to do with it (which is my recommendation)

2) Create a person package defining the Person type and import that package into both. I think person.Person is silly, which is why I wouldn't do this. database.Person or server.Person makes more sense to me. I mean at that point it all comes down to how you're reading, writing and storing Person, and that's unclear.